# Get the number and round to whole number

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm getting the miles from Google Map API V3 and displaying it in a textbox based on the from and to addresses. I want to parse out the number and round it off to the nearest whole number.

Miles = "29.9 mi" // i want the result as 30
Miles = "9.3 mi" // 10

I tried Math.round but it's returning NAN.

```
if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
        directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
        var miles = response.routes[0].legs[0].distance.text;
        miles = Math.round(miles);
        $('#TotalMiles').val(miles);
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `parseFloat` + `Math.ceil`:

```
var number = "9.3 mi";
console.log(Math.ceil(parseFloat(number)));
```

Answer (score 3):

Did you look at the JavaScript API for [round](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round)?

> **Syntax**
>
> `Math.round(x)`
>
> **Parameters**
>
> - `x` A number.
>
> **Description**
>
> If the fractional portion of number is .5 or greater, the argument is
>   rounded to the next higher integer. If the fractional portion of
>   number is less than .5, the argument is rounded to the next lower
>   integer.
>
> Because round is a static method of Math, you always use it as
>   Math.round(), rather than as a method of a Math object you created.

---

EDIT:

You need to convert the string into its parts to get the number

```
Miles = "29.9 mi"
var num = parseFloat(Miles);
Math.round(num);
```

and way to do it with a regular expression

```
Miles = "29 mi"
var rounded = Miles.replace(/(\d+(\.\d+)?)(\s?mi)/, function(match, number, x, units){   return Math.round(parseFloat(number)) + units });
console.log(rounded);
```

Comment: or Math.ceil() if you really want 9.3 to display 10

Comment: @Ram, helps if you put that info in your question. ;)

Comment: Did you input the number as an argument? Are you sure the argument is a number? NAN = Not a Number.

Answer (score 2):

you may need to split out the extra characters.

```
var str = "29.9 mi";
var number = str.split(" ");
var new_number = Math.round(parseFloat(number[0]));
```

This is a longwinded answer. In the end it would make more sense to tailor it to what you need exactly, but here I am just showing how to split on " " (space) and round the resulting string after parsing it as a float.

I would try KaeruCT's answer though. I don't think parseInt or parseFloat actually need the non numeric characters removed.

Answer (score 1):

Try `Math.round()`:

```
var number =29.9;
console.log(Math.round(number));
```